# Maven POM Dependency issues #3210

Tags: maven, graphql, osgi, aem, graphql-java

I am working on an AEM-Java project and facing an issue with graphql-java dependency where I am trying to add it on a maven project having a BND plugin. but once I add the dependency and try to build the code so the OSGI bundle is always in the installed state. I am not sure what I missing but looking like there is an other jar dependency on graphql-java.

I am getting this message while trying to add the dependency:

**[ERROR] [api-regions-exportsimports] com.adobe.aem.guides.aemspa.react:aem-guides-aem-spa.react.core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Bundle aem-guides-aem-spa.react.core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is importing package(s) [com.google.errorprone.annotations, org.reactivestreams, org.dataloader.stats, org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual, org.dataloader, com.google.errorprone.annotations.concurrent, javax.annotation.meta] in start level 20 but no bundle is exporting these for that start level. (com.adobe.aem.guides.aemspa.react:aem-guides-aem-spa.react.all:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)**

**Added dependency in core pom.xml and parent pom.xml with version 20.2 and tried 19 as well.**

Added this in core pom.xml -
*Import-Package: javax.annotation;version=0.0.0,!com.google.,!org.checkerframework.,!javax.annotation.,!graphql.com.google.,!sun.misc,*
-includeresource: graphql-java-[0-9.]*.jar;lib:=true*

I also raised this request on Adobe AEM Community forum and github discussion but no one was able to help. can anyone please help me here?

https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/aem-graphql-java/m-p/590600#M147441

https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/discussions/3210

Thank you,
Prince

Comment: Please give much more information: JDK version, Maven version ? Plugin versions, Do you use Maven Tycho? Does the error occur during build time or runtime? Also your pom files would be helpful...

Comment: Try also to include compile dependencies of graphql-java: "java-dataloader","reactive-streams" as dependencies and also in "includeresource".

Check how will look like and prevent import of not needed things with !somepackage.abc

Comment: [ERROR] The analyser found the following errors for author and publish : 
[ERROR] [api-regions-exportsimports] com.adobe.aem.guides.aemspa.react:aem-guides-aem-spa.react.core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Bundle aem-guides-aem-spa.react.core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is importing package(s) [com.google.errorprone.annotations, org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual, com.google.errorprone.annotations.concurrent, sun.misc, javax.annotation.meta] in start level 20 but no bundle is exporting these for that start level. (com.adobe.aem.guides.aemspa.react:aem-guides-aem-spa.react.all:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

After adding error

Comment: I am getting the same error.

Comment: -includeresource: graphql-java-[0-9.]*.jar;lib:=true,java-dataloader-[0-9.]*.jar;lib:=true,reactive-streams-[0-9.]*.jar;lib:=true

Comment: JDK 11, Maven 3.8.1, 
Error is occurring during build time.

Comment: You are preventing the import of those problematic packages?
like !com.google.errorprone.*, !org.checkerframework.*, !sun.misc,!javax.annotation.meta

Comment: I have updated the pom.xml with the code - 

<bnd><![CDATA[
Import-Package: javax.annotation;version=0.0.0,!com.google.,!org.checkerframework.,!graphql.com.google.,!sun.misc
-includeresource: graphql-java-[0-9.]*.jar;lib:=true,java-dataloader-[0-9.]*.jar;lib:=true,reactive-streams-[0-9.]*.jar;lib:=true
                                ]]></bnd>

And now I am not getting the build error. but now the servlet is in a satisfied state under the system/console/components. also, other servlets also went in satisfy state.

Comment: You need to check error logs - try to activate servlets/services  in osgi console and you should get why servlet/service is not started. Most probably some of imports should be not be prevented from import. Those which should not be prevented, most probably needs to be added as dependency & include resource

Comment: Also I believe on the end of Import-package you should have *;resolution:=optional